# Can I enable one-click-uninstall on in the Cinnamon menu?

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with the Cinnamon desktop, installed from PPA.

In Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon you can right click on an application in the menu and uninstall it directly. I haven't been able to find this in Ubuntu's Cinnamon.

How can I enable this feature in my version of Cinnamon? Or can I otherwise upgrade my Cinnamon to have the same features as that in Mint?

Comment: As this is not part of official ubuntu install, have you tried contracting the maintainer of the repository?

Comment: Which PPA are you using?

Comment: @Oli from here :- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/install-cinnamon-2-4-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Ashu, that's not the PPA...  This is: **ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly**

Comment: We're sorry, but *ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly* is a development version.  Development problems should be [filed as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev) so that the developers are aware of the problems and can fix them.  Therefore, this question is off-topic on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

what the cinnamon devs do is create a link to this feature, because the feature depend of the distro... So this feature need an specific support on your current distro (in this case ubuntu).
Is relatively easy add this feature to ubuntu if you want to use this with synaptic (thats will be copy the mint implementation to the right place on ubuntu), but if you don't want to use synaptic then you need use the feature with the ubuntu software center and this will be more difficult... Anyway there are an alternative implementation if you want to use this feature (and also with more features like search for packages or install a packages). You need to change the default cinnamon menu and use instead the Configurable Menu...

Please see that Configurable Menu is not an official Menu and the alternative implementation included on Configurable Menu is also not an official implementation, so use this as your risk... Any way i'm the author.

http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/171

Last version:
https://github.com/lestcape/Configurable-Menu